# Ubuntu installation on HD with LVM2

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I need to install Ubuntu alongside with Fedora. However Fedora is using LVM2 to utilize all the disc and Ubuntu 10.10 installer is not able to see or resize it. I don't have access rights to existing Fedora. How can I make room for Ubuntu without damaging Fedora filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I heard "[Ubuntu Desktop Alternative](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/alternative-download)" supports advanced installation (LVM, LSR, *etc*) contrary to "Ubuntu Desktop" which is quite dumb.

Comment: Good point! This is exactly what I need. Ubuntu installer that is able to handle LVM2.

Answer (score 1):

LVM2 depends on device-mapper which is a kernel module not included in the vanilla kernel so far. Probably the easiest way to get a live-distribution having the device-mapper patches applied is to look for a fedora live-cd. Just boot from it and use the provided tools to change your partition layout.

Answer (score 0):

If there is room left in the volume group, you could create logical volumes for Ubuntu in the manual partitioner during install.

If there isn't space, you'll have to manually shrink the Fedora partition, then shrink the logical volume, so there will be space in the volume group.

Or, once there is space in the volume group, you could then shrink the physical volume, then reduce the partition table size.  Then you have a free partition, where you could install Ubuntu in.

Comment: Well, Ubuntu installer says that disc has one 512MB partition only. And the remaining is unpartitioned. If I start Fedora, it says it's using some 50GB. So obviously I can't start manually partitioning from Ubuntu installer, as it would break the Fedora's LVM2.

Comment: The 512MB partition is probably the Fedora /boot disk.  Try using the Ubuntu Desktop Alternative installer.